# Why didn't Ahsoka assist the Rebellion after Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, star-wars-rebels

With the creation of The Clone Wars animated series, the characters introduced became canon.  So I've been wondering, after the series ended, nothing is ever heard of of Ahsoka Tano.  She simply leaves the Jedi Order behind and walks off into the sunset.  **But what ever became of her?**  One would think that a former Jedi with that much talent and potential would assist Yoda and Obi-Wan in taking down the Empire.  **So why did she not resurface after Order 66 was carried out?  Why did she not help the Rebels fight the Empire?**

Comment: Do we know for sure that she didn't? *Rebels* is filling in that time period now.

Comment: I'm just going off of the info posted on Wookiepedia and any other current documented histories of the Star Wars universe.  I know the media that came before the series won't have anything about her.  I actually haven't seen any of *Rebels*.

Comment: Yoda & Obi-Wan both went into hiding, why wouldn't she do the same? (And *they* weren't exactly active in trying to take down the Empire.) In fact, she may not even know about Order 66 happening.

Comment: It's not yet certain whether Ahsoka will make a return in Rebels. My gut instinct says yes, simply because she's too recognisable a character to waste by never mentioning her again; http://dorksideoftheforce.com/2014/11/15/ahsoka-tano-rumored-return-rebels/

Comment: @Adeptus, Ahsoka was very much in tune with the force, she probably would have sensed an event of that magnitude.

Comment: @Richard, one would think.  But as I said, I haven't watched Rebels.  Is it worth watching?

Comment: @Robert - I've not been watching (yet) but it's been getting some excellent reviews.

Comment: I've enjoyed Rebels, the ones I've seen anyway.  Also, with Ahsoka being intune both with the Force, *and* Anakin, I believe chances are good that she survived.  I doubt Anakin would have hunted her down quite so ruthlessly.

Comment: To be clear, I think you've got a good, valid question in there - I just think that in light of new/emerging materials, it's premature to assume that she *didn't* play a role in the early rebellion.

Comment: @phantom42, yeah, I kinda figured myself.  I'll probably place a bounty on it at a later date to bring attention back to it once more info has been released or delete it based on said info

Comment: @ThorinSchmidt I dunno, Anakin and Obi-Wan were like brothers and he was pretty ruthless towards him physically and verbally.  I think once he fully embraced the dark side, it wouldn't have mattered how much Ahsoka meant to him, he probably still would have hunted and killed her.

Comment: @Robert, well, could be. I didn't see that last season of Clone Wars, so I don't know adversarial they got toward each other near the end.  Most of the Rift came from Anakin's resentment at Obi-Wan "holding him back", which wouldn't be the case with Anakin and Ahsoka, since Anakin was the master in that relationship.

Comment: @ThorinSchmidt there was no hostility between the two at the end of the series.  Ahsoka was pissed at the council for the lack of faith they had in her and the fact that they tried to burn her for something she didn't do, but she and Anakin parted on friendly terms

Answer (score 14, accepted):

She *is* a member of the Rebel Alliance.

> As of *Star Wars Rebels* Episode 1x13 "Fire Across the Galaxy", we know she **is** a member of the Rebel Alliance. It stands to reason we might be seeing more of her. (I thought about adding a *Rebels* tag to the question, but that would negate masking the spoiler - but should probably be done in due time.)

Comment: I'm not in favour of having the entire answer be a spoiler.

Comment: @Richard, neither am I, actually, but thought it better to be careful, since the reveal is still rather new...

Comment: I've edited to give your answer some more visibility, without giving the game away

Comment: I still haven't watched Rebels so I didn't know that.  But the question was asked before that episode(Not trying to be rude or condescending, but I realize that that's how my comment reads).  Thanks for providing this answer, perhaps I should start watching the show.  Is it still getting good reviews?

Comment: No worries @Robert, at least I didn't interpret your comment as such. Regarding _Rebels_: It does, as far as I can tell. IMO I'd say that if you liked Clone Wars, chances are you'd like this one too, although I personally feel it is directed at a somewhat younger audience than its predecessor. On the other hand they got a fair amount of actors from the movies to voice their characters on the show (Tony Daniels, Frank Oz, Billy Dee Williams & JAMES EARL JONES!!)...

Answer (score 4):

From the canon, we never learned the fate of Ahsoka. After she walked away from the Order, we never learned what happened to her. There are many possibilities:

- She was killed by Empire.
- She turned to dark side to secretly assist the dark side like Inquisitor.
- She heard about Order 66 and went into exile.
- She did really assist Rebel Alliances.

Also, I want to point this out that you shouldn't specially treat probable survival of Ahsoka Tano. There were hundreds of Jedi in the Galaxy who survived Order 66 (Kanan is one of them). None of them assisted Rebel Alliances or maybe they did. We just don't know.

**Update:**
She really did assist the Rebel Alliance. Source:

> S01E13 of *Star Wars: Rebels* TV series

Answer (score 2):

Ahsoka Tano *was* a member of the Rebel Alliance. A key member, in fact, and one of the earliest members.

SPOILER ALERTS:

A year after the Fall of the Republic and Jedi Order, Ahsoka joined Bail Organa's rebellion, arguably the first *actual* organized groups that were fighting the Galactic Empire. She took over his intelligence network and became the first 'Fulcrum' agent, a specialized rebel intelligence agent. She was vital to the early rebellion, as she was responsible for directing spies and gathering information and using that information to give rebels missions. She was one of the few who reported directly to Bail Organa. Since Ahsoka was the head of early Rebel Intelligence, she (and other Fulcrum agents) were supposed to keep their identities as secret as possible. Only Bail and the Ghost crew knew who she was.

She worked as Fulcrum for 14 years until she was thought MIA on Malachor after her duel with Darth Vader and the subsequent collapse of the Sith Temple. However, Ahsoka survived, and while she was stranded on Malachor for a few years, we can assume she continued helping the Rebel Alliance behind the scenes since she wasn't in the OT. She was confirmed to have survived past the Fall of the Empire and the New Republic Era. She and Naq Med were the only confirmed beings who were fully trained in the Old Jedi Order to have done this.

You can find all this information in the novel, *Ahsoka* and the tv show, Star Wars Rebels.